# Partial sorting own adapter. Why ListView isn't totally sorted?

Tags: android, listview, sorting

My application contains ListView of all instaled apps (TextView and RatingBar) and allows sorting elements of ListView according to ranking (selected in the menu).
It means, after choosing option from menu sort->ranking->descending f.e., ListView which contains name of installed apps and ranking, should be sorted in descending order according to ranking. The problem is that the ListView isn't totally sorted. It works but without few elements, but.. after scrolling screen is ok. 
I think that problem may be in my onRatingChanged, but I haven't any idea how to change it. Could I get some clue?

Piece of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences3";
    public SharedPreferences pref;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    public ListView listView;
    public List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    public PackageManager pm;
    public App app_packages[];
    public AppAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefEditor = pref.edit(); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        pm=getPackageManager();
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        app_packages=new App[packages.size()];

        int i=0; 
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
        {
            app_packages[i]=new App(pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString());
            i++;
        }

         adapter = new AppAdapter(this, R.layout.app, app_packages);
         listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
         }


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<App> 
    {
        private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences3";
        public SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        public SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor=pref.edit();

       Context context; 
       App applications_array[]=null;
       int layoutResourceId;

       public AppAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, App[] applications_array)
       {
           super(context, layoutResourceId, applications_array);  
           this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
           this.context=context;
           this.applications_array=applications_array;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {           
           View app=convertView;  
           AppHolder holder=null;

           if(app==null) 
           {
               LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();     
               app=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

               holder=new AppHolder();
               holder.textView=(TextView)app.findViewById(R.id.appTitle);
               holder.ratingBar=(RatingBar)app.findViewById(R.id.appScore);
               app.setTag(holder);
           }
           else
           {
               holder=(AppHolder) app.getTag();
           }



        holder.ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
           public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                prefEditor.putFloat("rating"+applications_array[position].title, rating).commit();

                            applications_array[position].rating=rating;
                            switch(pref.getString("sort", ""))
                            { 
                                case "r_up": Sort_r_up(); 
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                                    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getPosition(applications_array[position]));
                                    break;
                                case "r_down": Sort_r_down();
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getPosition(applications_array[position]));
                                    break;
                            }
                } 
                }); 
                holder.textView.setText(applications_array[position].title);
                holder.ratingBar.setRating(pref.getFloat("rating"+applications_array[position].title, 0.0f));

            return app;
       } 
    }


    static class AppHolder
    { 
        TextView textView; 
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }

    public class App
    {
        public String title;
        public float rating;


        public App(){}

        public App(String title)
        {
            this.title=title;
            this.rating=0.0f;
        }

    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {

                 case R.id.r_up:
                prefEditor.putString("sort", "r_up").commit();
            Sort_r_up(); 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.r_down:
                prefEditor.putString("sort", "r_down").commit();
                Sort_r_down();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public void Sort_r_up()
    {
         adapter.sort(new Comparator<App>()
         {
             public int compare(App arg0, App arg1) {
                    if(arg0.rating>arg1.rating)
                        return 1;
                    else 
                        return -1;
                }
         });
    }

    public void Sort_r_down() 
    {
         adapter.sort(new Comparator<App>()
         {  
             public int compare(App arg0, App arg1) {
                    if(arg0.rating>=arg1.rating)
                        return -1;
                    else 
                        return 1; 
             }    
         });

    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed, that when adapter is sorted , only visible items of ListView have correct ranking, others are equal to zero. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not describing correctly how you are sorting. You not only sort according to rating but also alphabetically on title when the ratings are equal. Take that first out.

You forgot for the switch() break; statements after the listView.smoothScrollToPosition();

Instead of

```
object.rating=rating;
```

I would also write

```
data[position].rating = rating;
```

How terrible your variable names:

```
public App app_packages[];
App data[]=null;
View app=convertView; 
final App object=data[position];
```

Try to make your code more readable.

Comment: Show how you did it please. And did you put data[position].rating = rating;? Or data[position] = object;?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
prefEditor.putFloat("rating"+object.title, rb.getRating()).commit();
```

to

```
prefEditor.putFloat("rating"+object.title, rating).commit();
```

Further in onRatingChanged you use the wrong object I think. You should not take a final one but use someting like

```
object= ratingBar.getTag();
```

And before you have used

```
setTag(object);
```

Well untested.

And please change

```
static class AppHolder
{ 
    TextView appTitle; 
    RatingBar appScore;
}
```

to

```
static class AppHolder
{ 
    TextView textView; 
    RatingBar ratingBar;
}
```

because your code is difficult to read with these changing descriptions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean with setTag(object) and what should I change regarding object. Could you explain it in more detail? I'll be grateful

Comment: After:               holder.ratingBar.setRating(pref.getFloat("rating"+applications_array[position].title, 0.0f));
 add the statement:  holder.ratingBar.setTag(position); In onRatingChanged() put following code to get position back:               int position = (Integer) ratingBar.getTag();
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position: " + position
               + "\nratingBar.getRating: " + ratingBar.getRating()
               + "\nrating: " + rating
               , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();